# Scuola Normale Superiore's IVth year Admission Exam 2014 - Probability question (Exercise 3)

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be real-valued random variables with the same law and such that the product $XY$ is almost surely zero. Prove that $P(X=0)\geq 1/2$. Find an explicit example such that $P(X=0)=1/2$.

Link [here](https://www.sns.it/sites/default/files/2021-04/2010%202019%20prove%20scienze%204%20anno.pdf).

**(My attempt is in the answers - this is a question+answer post)**

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$1=P(\{X=0\}\cup\{Y=0\})+P(\{X\neq 0\}\cap \{Y\neq 0\})$$
And also, using the a.s. zero product assumption (i.e. $P(XY=0)=1$)
$$P(\{X\neq 0\}\cap \{Y\neq 0\})=P(XY\neq 0)=0$$
Therefore, since $X\sim Y$:
$$1=P(\{X=0\}\cup\{Y=0\})\leq P(X=0)+P(Y=0)=2P(X=0)$$
from which we conclude that $P(X=0)\geq 1/2$. Now take $X\sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ and $Y=1-X$. We have
$$P(Y=1)=P(X=0)=1/2,\,P(Y=0)=P(X=1)=1/2$$
So $Y\sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$. To conclude that $X,Y$ satisfies all the required criteria:
$$P(XY=0)=P(X(1-X)=0)=P(\{X=1\}\cup\{X=0\})=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\mathcal{N} = \{XY = 0\}$, we know that $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{N}) = 1$. Next, we have that $\{Y\neq 0\}\cap \mathcal{N}\subset \{X = 0\}$, it follows that $\mathbb{P}(\{Y\neq 0\}\cap \mathcal{N})\leq \mathbb{P}(X = 0)$. Since $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{N}) = 1$ one has $\mathbb{P}(\{Y\neq 0\}\cap \mathcal{N}) = \mathbb{P}(Y\neq 0)$ thus $\mathbb{P}(Y\neq 0)\leq \mathbb{P}(X=0)$. Finally, as $X,Y$ have the same law, it follows that $\mathbb{P}(Y\neq 0) = \mathbb{P}(X\neq 0)$, we conclude $\mathbb{P}(X\neq 0) \leq \mathbb{P}(X= 0)$, but we also know $\mathbb{P}(X=0) + \mathbb{P}(X\neq 0)=1$, then we conclude $\mathbb{P}(X=0)\geq 1/2$.

Consider $\Omega = \{u,v\}$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and the probability $\mathbb{P}$ defined by $\mathbb{P}(u) = \mathbb{P}(v) = 1/2$. Define $X(\omega) = \mathscr{1}_{\{\omega = u\}}$ and $Y(\omega) = \mathscr{1}_{\{\omega = v\}}$, then we have that $X,Y$ have the same law and $XY = 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=0) = 1/2$.